# Possibility of causing MD5 value changes if a file is uploaded to a server and re-download from the server

Tags: file, md5

I have a case where there is a necessity to download various files from different servers. And, I checked on the MD5 for two files for identicalness and realize they are different. But, after I have checked in term of content, they are exactly the same, including the total of bytes they have for each file.

My main question here is that are there any possibility where the same file will have a different MD5 value after it has been uploaded to a server and re-download from it? In fact, I am working on around 25 different servers for comparisons. So, I need to know if it is because of the server or any other issue that caused this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty safe bet that the two files really are different, just in some subtle way that isn't visible with the method you're using to compare them.  On a Mac or Linux box, try running:

```
od -c file1 > file1-od.txt
od -c file2 > file2-od.txt
diff file1-od.txt file2-od.txt
```

If you're using Windows, install the free Cygwin package to get the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible.  The files are different.
Use a DIFF utility to see where the discrepancy lies.  WinDIFF, diff in linux,etc